# What is the retry behavior used when calling a mutating admission webhook?

Tags: kubernetes

I am setting up a mutating admission webhook for my cluster, and I don't see anything in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#configure-admission-webhooks-on-the-fly) about retries/backoff used when the request to the webhook endpoint fails. Is this setting just the same as the retry/backoff behavior setting for the whole Kube api server, or is there a default setting used?

Comment: Have you read about auditing in Kubernetes ? Take a look https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#webhook-backend

Comment: I have, but I don't see what it has to do with setting retry behavior for the webhook request.

Comment: Have you seen those lines --audit-webhook-initial-backoff specifies the amount of time to wait after the first failed request before retrying. Subsequent requests are retried with exponential backoff ?

Comment: @Malgorzata that appears to be specific to audit webhooks, which I think are different from admission webhooks. Am I missing something?

Comment: Following. I have sarched the internet as well as checked the k8s code and could not find any logic for retry. There is logic for retry on auth path but not generic.